# Can a Flash component check its own use count?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, components, actionscript-2

Is there any way for a Flash component (or an Actionscript class linked to a MovieClip in general) to check or return its own use count?  I am interested in answers for both AS2 and AS3.

Comment: In AS3 create a singleton class put a counter in it. In AS2 well its time to move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's anything already built in but you can easily achieve this with a static var like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static var classCreationCount:int = 0;
    public function MyClass()
    {
        classCreationCount++;
    }
    public static function getClassCreationCount():int
    {
        return classCreationCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a use count, it's an instantiation count.  Counting uses would mean counting the number of times an instance is retained by another class - and there's no way to keep track of that, unless you manually increase a counter every time you assign a variable, and decrease it when you set it to `null`.

Comment: Okay @weltraumpirat I'll agree this isn't a use count in terms of how many of a class are still part of the overall graph of "active" instances but for the most part this should achieve the goal, otherwise the only thing I can think of is, 1 some profiler, or 2 if you're interested in items attached to the display tree then traverse that and look for if each object "is" WhateverClass.  This seemed to be what the OP was looking for though.

Comment: If it's a Display class, it could decrement the counter when removed from stage. The increment should probably be moved to added to stage in that case.

Comment: Good call @Amy, you can also get "static code analysis" usage of a class in Eclipse/Flash Builder by clicking the class name in the definition (public class Xxxxxxx) and hitting Ctrl+Shift+G

Answer (score 0):

(ActionScript 3 only) Another possibility would be, using a Dictionary with weak referenced keys to keep track of the referenced/retained objects at runtime. By checking which instance is in the dictionary, you get a rough idea, what's going. But that is a nondeterministic approach, because you never know, when the the garbage collection is running.

Another idea would be an ObjectPool. This could be implemented rudimentary in a couple of minutes, but needed to be used consequently throughout the whole application.